# Installing cppman -> output not shown in right format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, fedora, linux-mint

I've tried to install [cppman](https://github.com/Aitjcize/cppman) in Fedora 19 or Linux mint 15 and it installs successfully. But when I try to use it I get the error:

```
Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've installed it in Ubuntu 12.04 and had no problem. Can you help me?

Update: I fixed this problem, but I have a new problem. when for example I enter `cppman cout` the output shown is not in right format:

"1mNAME0m
       std::cout - Standard output stream

1mTYPE0m
       object
       
1mSYNOPSIS0m
       extern ostream cout;

1mDESCRIPTION0m
       Object of class ostream that represents the standard output stream oriented to narrow characters (of type
         char

```
   ). It corresponds to the C stream stdout."
```

It seems that I need to install or configure something. Can you help me?

Comment: do you have SELinux in enforcing mode?

Comment: @dawud: I don't know much about SELinux. How can I check that. But I think that SELinux is not installed in Linux mint but I have the same problem there.

Comment: In Fedora it is enabled by default. Mint, being a Debian derivative, is less likely to have it enabled. Find out issuing `sestatus -v`

Comment: @dawud: yes, it is in enforcing mode but as you mentioned linux mint doesn't have SELinux, but it has the same problem so the problem is not because of that.

Comment: Then add to your question the steps you took to install that software. It might be helpful in order to find the culprit.